# Flutter set maxWidth on Stack with constrainedBox

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

in my simple implementation of `Card` don't have `maxWidth` and when i rotate application that fills the width and i'm trying to avoiding that and setting `maxWith:300.0', my code doesn't work

```
return Container(
    color: Color(0xffeeeeee),
    child: ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300),
      child: Stack(
        overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 200.0,
            color: Colors.indigo,
          ),
          Positioned(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.3,
              left: 10.0,
              top: 95.0,
              child: Card(
                elevation: 2.0,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white12),
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    ));
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Did you ever find a solution?